# visionOS weird behaviour on NavigationStack title

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack, visionos

I have a very simple navigation architecture so far, I left inner views (`CourseDetail` and `CourseRows`) as clean as possible to make sure there's nothing inside provoking the issue. Here's how it looks like.-

```
NavigationStack {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack {
            ForEach(modelData.courses) { course in
                NavigationLink {
                    CourseDetail(course: course)
                        .navigationTitle(course.fullTitle)
                    } label: {
                        CourseRow(course: course)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Language Transfer")
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
    }
}
```

When I click in a `CourseRow`, the app correctly navigates to `CourseDetail`, showing `course.fullTitle` in the top `navigationBar`, **BUT** if I go back and click a different course quickly enough (I'm guessing the transition is not over yet), the first click doesn't navigate, and if a click again, I see the right `course.fullTitle` for a second and then it's replaced for the previous `course.fullTitle` I navigated to the first time.

I'm struggling to find where the issue is, is it possible that it's just a bug in the beta?

Comment: As you mention, VisionOS is still very much in beta. These sorts of anomalies are very common in early version OS' especially from Apple. It's important to remember that you're working on the very very fringe of the technology at the moment and bugs like this are to be expected. It would be in the best interest of the entire community if you could file a feedback with Apple via the built in "Feedback Assistant" app.

Comment: Thank you @BrandonStillitano, I just felt like checking in case I was making an obvious mistake (it wouldn't be the first time :), but you may be right and it's just a beta issue. Seems you can't even select `visionOS` in feedback assistant yet, but will stay tuned to report the issue.

Comment: No probs @ssantos :) That's a real shame that they haven't added it to FA yet, I suppose with time they will, but for now, developers are stuck on their own.